# How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java

Tags: java, arrays, annotations

I am thinking this may not be possible in Java because annotation and its parameters are resolved at compile time. I have an interface as follows,

```
public interface FieldValues {
   String[] FIELD1 = new String[]{"value1", "value2"};
}
```

and another class as,

```
@SomeAnnotation(locations = {"value1", "value2"})
public class MyClass {
   ....
}
```

I mark many classes with the annotation and I would like to know if I can avoid specifying the strings in every annotation I would instead prefer to use

```
@SomeAnnotation(locations = FieldValues.FIELD1)
public class MyClass {
   ....
}
```

However this gives compilation errors like annotation value should be an array initializer etc. Does someone know how I can use a String constant or String[] constant to supply value to an annotation?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Compile constants [can only be primitives and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> **15.28. Constant Expressions**
>
> A compile-time *constant expression* is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type `String`
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type `String`
> - [...] operators [...]
> - Parenthesized expressions whose contained expression is a constant expression.
> - Simple names that refer to constant variables.
> - Qualified names of the form *TypeName* . *Identifier* that refer to constant variables.

Actually in java there is no way to protect items in an array. At runtime someone can always do `FieldValues.FIELD1[0]="value3"`, therefore the array cannot be really constant if we look deeper.

Comment: @TacB0sS, enums are not constant expressions.

Comment: Well... perhaps you should give it a go and let me know... I use them all the time :)

Comment: A more relevant spec is under [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1-300). In addition to a constant expression, an annotation value can be an _array initializer_, _class literal_, or _enum constant_.

Comment: Aha! I was using a Long, not a long..... Solved my issue!!! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @TacB0sS you can use `enum` in annotatios, but they are not compile-time constant. The difference becomes apparent when you write `static final EnumType VARIABLE = EnumType.ENUM_CONSTANT;` and try to use `VARIABLE` in an annotation; it won’t work. You can only use `EnumType.ENUM_CONSTANT` which is not a constant expression, but specifically allowed in annotations (and `switch` statements).

Comment: Wow! Totally blown away with this revelation after years of doing Java. Was using `Integer` and pulling my hair.

Answer (score 51):

You can use a constant (i.e. a static, final variable) as the parameter for an annotation.  As a quick example, I use something like this fairly often:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyTestClass
{
    private static final int TEST_TIMEOUT = 60000; // one minute per test

    @Test(timeout=TEST_TIMEOUT)
    public void testJDK()
    {
        assertTrue("Something is very wrong", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

Note that it's possible to pass the `TEST_TIMEOUT` constant straight into the annotation.

Offhand, I don't recall ever having tried this with an array, so you may be running into some issues with slight differences in how arrays are represented as annotation parameters compared to Java variables?  But as for the other part of your question, you could definitely use a constant String without any problems.

EDIT: I've just tried this with a String array, and didn't run into the problem you mentioned - however the compiler *did* tell me that the "attribute value must be constant" despite the array being defined as `public static final String[]`.  Perhaps it doesn't like the fact that arrays are mutable?  Hmm...

Comment: Tough Luck for me ! Oh yah I was able to pass Strings/Numbers but not arrays. I will spend a bit more time on this and if nothing works out will accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be that the mutability of the FIELD1 array is the issue here. You're allowed to declare the array with an array initializer because nothing else can have access to that array and so it cannot be changed later.

Comment: This solves my problem. Just needed to share a String constant between annotations and code. Thanks!

Comment: static final variable is not the only prerequisite. If you try to dynamically calc the variable you'll get the same error message.

Answer (score 14):

> Does someone know how I can use a
>   String constant or String[] constant
>   to supply value to an annotation?

Unfortunately, you can't do this with arrays.  With non-array variables, the value must be final static.

Comment: It must be final but does not have to be static.

Answer (score 12):

You're not supplying it with an array in your example. The following compiles fine:

```
public @interface SampleAnnotation {
    String[] sampleValues();
}

public class Values {
    public static final String val0 = "A";
    public static final String val1 = "B";

    @SampleAnnotation(sampleValues={ val0, val1 })
    public void foo() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It is being supplied with an array in the example, just not one that is created directly in the annotation declaration.

Answer (score 5):

> I am thinking this may not be possible in Java because annotation and its parameters are resolved at compile time.

With Seam 2 http://seamframework.org/ you were able to resolve annotation parameters at runtime, with expression language inside double quotes.

In Seam 3 http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Solder, this feature is the module Seam Solder

Comment: No, you didn't resolve _the parameters_ at runtime. The parameter were resolved at compile-time. That they were then used to do something at runtime has literally nothing to do with when their values were set.

Answer (score -3):

You can use enum and refer that enum in annotation field

Comment: You should add an example.