# Webservice declaration with static vars not possible?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb

when creating a Webservice, can I somehow use static String vars?

```
@WebService(
        portName = Util.PORT,
        serviceName = Util.SERVICE,
        targetNamespace = ...,
        endpointInterface = ...)
public class MyWsClass implements WsInterface
```

result:

```
The value for annotation attribute WebService.portName must be a constant expression
```

So can't I use static vars?

Comment: How have you defined Util.PORT?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

relevant SO question: [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)

It is possible to set the annotation parameter values from constants if they are Strings or numbrs and declared as static final.