# passing value to custom annotation in java

Tags: java, annotations

**I am using custom annotation with aspectj.**

```
@TestLoggingAnnotation(setMessage = "I want to set value here")
public void get() {

    String retString = null;
    String message = "DEFAULT";

    if (message == "DEFAULT") {

        retString = "Default Logging";

    } else {

        retString = "Custom Logging";
    }
}
```

The above is just simple and sample code. My requirement is that I want to pass the parameter value after resulting from method.

In my case I want set `retString` value to `setMessage` in custom parameter.

Comment: afaik, custom annotation methods cannot have parameters.  But I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: @CPerkins `@TestLoggingAnnotation(setMessage = "I want to set value here")` you can call an thing to `setMessage = "I want to set value here".` I want to set value of setMessage. now it is ok ?

Comment: there is another reply on stackoverflow for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime

Comment: I'm writing it as a comment in case I'm wrong - but annotation are not exactly a part of your run-time code. As their name states, they only annotate. They come to mark something that was set in compile time on a class or field. You can't use variables in annotations because the data is decided on in compile time.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, annotations can only take compile constants and cant be assigned values at runtime, though their value can be used at runtime using @Retention.

[discussion follows here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestLoggingAnnotation{
    String setMessage ();
}
```

now use reflection to extract and set method param i doubt we can do this with local varibles.