# I have a java annotation which takes a string constant as a argument , how can I Pass a string variable to the same?

Tags: java

For Eg  `@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using="//input[@name='Username']")`  here I want to replace the value of the string constant  `"//input[@name='Username']"` with a string variable , even though I declare the variable as final I am unable to pass the variable as a parameter. I want to write like this

```
final   static String Username_xpath="//input[@name='Username']";   
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using=Username_xpath)
```

Comment: You can find further comments on the same type of question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)

Answer (score 6):

No,you can not use variable in Annotation,only constant is permitted.

the following will work,because here `USERNAME_XPATH` is a constant:

```
final static String USERNAME_XPATH="//input[@name='Username']";
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using=USERNAME_XPATH)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a variable as an annotation value because the annotation is already evaluated at compile time.

Therefore only compile time constants (`static final`) can be used as values in annotations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Plonus. its clear now.  any work around to overcome this limitation as in my case all the variables are stored in a xml file and I want to pass them to this annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are designed for compile-time or deployment-time processing. At this point you do not have any runtime variables. Therefore it is not possible to use variables in association with annotations.