# Using ENUM for Profile, but expecting a String

Tags: java, spring, enums

I'm trying to use an Enum to define the different profiles my Spring application might use.

This is my enum Profiles.java

```
public enum Profiles {

    DEVELOPMENT("dev"),
    TEST("test"),
    PRODUCTION("prod");

    private final String code;

    private Profiles(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

I'm using it in a file to configure the properties place holders.

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyPlaceholderConfig {

    @Profile(Profiles.DEVELOPMENT)
    public static class DevelopmentConfig {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("props/application-dev.properties"));
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.TEST)
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("props/application-test.properties"));
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.PRODUCTION)
    public static class ProductionConfig {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application-test.properties"));
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }
    }
}
```

However it is complaining at @Profile that its getting incompatible types, got Profiles expected String. I feel like I'm missing something really silly.

Comment: What are \@Configuration, \@Profile and \@Bean? (ignore the extra \\)

Comment: That is from Spring libraries to configure all the components of the Spring application using different profiles, so I can customize the components and configure depending on what mode the application is running in, dev, test, prod, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Profile expects a [String array](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) (implemented as varargs) as its argument

```
@Profile(Profiles.DEVELOPMENT.name())
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Enum resolve to "dev" since that is the value of Profiles.DEVELOPMENT?

Comment: No `name` just returns the name of the enum name. If you want to return `dev` add a getter for the `code` field...:)

Comment: This will not work, you will get: Attribute value must be constant

Comment: @MaciejMiklas you are correct. jkratz55 can you uncheck this answer and I will delete?

Comment: @jkratz55 is you wish to accept Martin's answer I will delete this post

Answer (score 3):

I think this will NOT work. I tried it in Java 8 and compiler complains that  "Attribute value must be a constant".

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java?rq=1) it can only be primitive or String.

Possible solution is:

```
@Profile(SpringProfiles.TEST)
public static class SpringProfiles {
    public static final String TEST = "test"; 

}
```

Even thought @Profile expects String[] this works - I guess there is some implicit conversion between String and String[].