# spring pass value from property file to annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have application.properties file for spring app which contains some simple properties:

```
queue=my.test.q
```

in the java code i need to specify the queue to @RabbitListener:

```
@Component
public class Handler {    
    @RabbitListener(queues = "my.test.q")
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
       ...
    }
```

that would work, but i want to pass parameter to the annotation, i've tried the following but none of them worked.

```
    @Component
    public class Handler {
        @Value("${queue}")
        private String queueName;

        @RabbitListener(queues = @Value("${queue}")  <-- not working
        @RabbitListener(queues = queueName))     <--- not working
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
           ...
        }
```

is it possible to that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you can see in the [javadoc for the @RabbitListener annotation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.4.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListener.html#queues--), the queues attribute is a table of Strings, so you cannot assign an annotation to it. You also cannot assign variables to annotation attributes at all in Java, as they are required to be [compile constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java).

I cannot test it right now, but the javadoc seems to suggest that this should work (note, that it says it may return SpEL expressions):

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue}")     
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @RabbitListener(queues = "${queue}"))   have extra closing bracket! Please remove, I dont have edit permission :)

Comment: Good catch, removed :)

Comment: This suggestion works indeed. You just put in the brackets an application property (works with dots also, e.g. my.application.property) and it works as a placeholder

Comment: This method also worked for spring kafka. 

`@KafkaListener(topics = "${application.topic}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")`
    `public void listenWithHeaders(...)`