# Set description from property file for swagger @schema in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, resourcebundle, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm working on spring boot(v2.5.6) with dependency openapi-ui(v1.5.2) for swagger UI. I want to set description and other attribute such as required in @schema. The problem is I need to read this value from a property(resource-bundle). Also I want to read other attribute such as min/max/.. from some properties.

I'v tried below code but not worked:

```
@Schema( description ="{postalCode.description}" ,required ="{postalCode.required}")
String postalCode;
```

whereas postalCode.description is a property key  in a resource bundle.

Is There any way to use some *dictionary* like properties for swagger?

Comment: Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126836/spring-pass-value-from-property-file-to-annotation/32127068) the examples they provide use a $ sign in the attribute like this: `description ="${postalCode.description}"`. Does this work?

Comment: Hello, in your swagger configuration have used @PropertySource to specify the location of your properties files ? can you  add your swagger configuration class ?

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC Yes, but didn't work, maybe it need extra configuration

Comment: I am not sure how does Spring resolve this. It probably interpretes the `${}` in its annotation processor logic. Unfortunately I assume the @Schema annotation does not get processed by Spring, but you could theoretically implement your own annotation processing as described in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder). I have not done it myself.

Comment: Another idea, search if you could make Spring process other annotations as well, if it is at all possible. Just a wild guess.

Comment: @CheikhHAIBALA not worked on model and its fields, but ok for controller

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC thanks for your reply, I'll try annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can add file with swagger properties and then add configuration for it in Application.java:
`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:swagger-messages.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")`.

Then you have to use `description ="${postalCode.description}"` (add $)
and set `springdoc.api-docs.resolve-schema-properties` to `true`.

source: https://springdoc.org/faq.html