# How can I add a queue listener at runtime in JMS Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, messaging, spring-jms

I have already a listener which listen to a fixed queue. I would like to change it so I can add a listener at runtime.

For example a producer reads files for 10 users and writes messages to 10 JMS queues (each user has its own queue). Now I want to register new queue at runtime so that each queue gets its own listener.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
@JmsListener(destination = JmsConfig.INSERT_PRODUCT_QUEUE, containerFactory = "queueFactory")
public void listen(@Payload ProductData[] productDataArray, MessageHeaders headers, Message message) throws JMSException {
    try {
        DefaultImportService defaultImportService = (DefaultImportService) applicationContext.getBean("getDefaultImportService");
        defaultImportService.run(productDataArray, String.valueOf(headers.get("manufacturer")), String.valueOf(headers.get("tenant")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error", e);
    }
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(user);
    connectionFactory.setUserName(passwort);
    ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy policy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
    policy.setQueuePrefetch(10);
    connectionFactory.setPrefetchPolicy(policy);

    return connectionFactory;
}

 @Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> queueFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    factory.setConcurrency("200");
    factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: What is a "JMS query"?

Comment: a query where jms messages are written in order to have a listener which consume those messages

Comment: I think you mean a **queue**. There is no such thing as a *query* in JMS.

Comment: yes queue is correct word, edited the question

Comment: Extremely valid question. Just because you have 10 or so jms queues doesn't mean you need the same number of jms listeners. In fact, you can and should be able to use the different instances of the same listener class to read messages from the queues by passing the queue name at the time of the instance creation. I think this is a bad design and a flaw in the spring framework. Why can't we reuse it?

Comment: However, there seems to have a solution. Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862279/using-passed-in-value-for-jmslisteners-destination-paramter