# DefaultStringSet with

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-annotations

I work on Android project with AndroidAnnotations and I want to use it for SharedPreferences. I want to use `@DefaultStringSet`. When I want to define default value with a `String[]` I got error:

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

The same happens for `HashSet`. I also tried to define public static variable of type `String[]`, but nothing changes. 
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java?rq=1) there is no way to set constant for anything but primitives and Strings.

I looked for examples, but found nothing. 
So what is the way to initialize this preference, is this doable?

I work on AndroidAnnotations 4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array initializer is also a constant expression, that is how it can be used in annotations:

```
@DefaultStringSet({"one", "two", "three"})
```