# Need to pass a parameter to @Test(description) in testNg

Tags: java, testng

Im making a cross browser script using selenium in java + TestNg

In my tests @Test I need to pass the **browser** type in to Test Description. Something like below [to make report more meaningful]

@Test(description = "Login with Admin"- browser + **browserNameVariable** )

I pass "browser" as a testng parameter

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your `browserNameVariable`variable should be constant. See answers from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java) .