# How to make a compile time constant NaN or POSITIVE_INFINITY in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I tried:

```
import kotlin.Double.Companion.POSITIVE_INFINITY
import kotlin.Double.Companion.NaN

const val inf = POSITIVE_INFINITY
const val nan = NaN
```

But I get:

> Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value

The reason I need to do this is because of [Junit5's parametrized tests](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/#Value-Source):

```
 @ParameterizedTest
 @ValueSource(doubles = doubleArrayOf(nan, inf, -2* epsilon,  1.5, -0.5, 1.0 + 2* epsilon))
 fun ensureNotAProbability(number: Double)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Due to some limitations of Java annotations (described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067863/1097451)) the things 'passed to an annotation' can only be compile-time constants. Therefore I would need a compile time NaN, positive, and negative infinities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use the fact that the IEEE 754 standard guarantees `0.0 / 0.0` to be NaN and `1.0 / 0.0` to be +∞:

```
@Suppress("DIVISION_BY_ZERO")
const val NAN: Double = 0.0 / 0.0

@Suppress("DIVISION_BY_ZERO")
const val INFINITY: Double = 1.0 / 0.0

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(NAN) // NaN
    println(INFINITY) // Infinity
}
```