# Read property file by using MessageSource in Spring at compile-time

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties-file

I have a one trouble (sorry for my English)

I read property from file by `MessageSource` ( org.springframework.context.MessageSource ):

```
public class SomeConstants {

   @Autowired
   private static MessageSource messageSource;
   private static final Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();

   public static final String NULL_MESSAGE = messageSource
       .getMessage( "propertyKey", new Object[]{}, locale );
}
```

Property file:

```
propertyKey = "Some message"
```

And I'm trying to pass `NULL_MESSAGE`, from `SomeConstants` class, to `@NotNull` annotation ( javax.validation.constraints.NotNull ) as message parameter:

```
@NotNull( message = NULL_MESSAGE )
```

And when try to compile this, get compilation error (I use Maven to build project):

```
[ERROR] NULL_MESSAGE value must be a constant expression
```

It is possible to set value by `MessageSource` during compilation or I should solve it by another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java) TL;DR: it's not possible

Comment: I found some another solution here, thanks!