# Annotation Arguments with Generics Class

Tags: java, generics, interface

I would like to understand of this issue

```
public class DogController extends FeedCommonController<DogModel extends CommonAnimalModel, FARMER_1_AUTH> {
  // something

 // This is working - but there is duplication
  @Security.Authenticated(FARMER_1_AUTH.class)
  public boolean feed_it() {
    // nothing special
    DogModel.getRandom().feed_it();
  }
}

public class CatController extends FeedCommonController<CatModel extends CommonAnimalModel, FARMER_2_AUTH> {
  // something

  // This is working - but there is duplication 
  @Security.Authenticated(FARMER_2_AUTH.class)
  public boolean feed_it() {
    // nothing special
     CatModel.getRandom().feed_it();
  }
}
```

And  I want to simplify the code and remove the duplicate methods, but I cannot put Class type to annotation.

```
public abstract class CommonAnimalController< T extends CommonAnimalModel, XXXXXX> {

   @Security.Authenticated(XXXXXX.class) // <-- Here is a problem with declaration 
   public boolean feed_it() {
      T.getRandom().feed_it();
   }

}
```

```
/**
Get Token From HTTP Request from Actual Thread
*/
public class Security {

  @With(AuthenticatedAction.class)
  @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface Authenticated {
    Class<? extends Authenticator> value() default Authenticator.class;
  }

}
```

Concept with Annotation is already created and implemented on hundred classes. So its not possible make huge changes. But Its some Elegant way how to solved this?

Comment: since you are sharing the code, make it simple, share everything for a compilable code. Are missing the mdoels. DogModel, etc.  Possibly all in a single code place so one can copy paste your code and check deeper.

Comment: extended is not even a java syntax

Comment: ITs Simple code, and its not question about compilation.. but about how to design the code and what patterns to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in one question.
First problem you have is: How to get a class instance of generics type T
This is answered here: [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

The second problem you have, is how to avoid passing a constant to the annotation. 
You will have a compliation error **"Attribute value must be constant"**
For this second problem seems there is no simple way to achieve it in Java. (pheraps I am wrong) 
See this answer: [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java?rq=1)

**Solution for problem1**

```
public abstract class CommonAnimalController<T extends CommonAnimalModel, XXXXXX> {
    final Class<XXXXXX> typeParameterClass;

    public CommonAnimalController(Class<XXXXXX> typeParameterClass) {
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }
    @Security.Authenticated(typeParameterClass)  // you will have "Attribute value must be constant"
    public boolean feed_it() {
        return T.getRandom().feed_it();
    }
}
```