# Pass a tab as an annotation parameter: "attribute value must be constant"

Tags: java, spring

I have a class containing multiple constants and I would like to return all the constants except one in order to make some tests. I have made a simple method but it return the error "attribute value must be constant" when I use it in my annotation.

```
public final class RolesConstants {

    public static final String APP_SYSTEM = "APP_SYSTEM";
    public static final String APP_CLIENT = "APP_CLIENT";
    public static final String APP_PROFESSIONAL = "APP_PROFESSIONAL";
    public static final String APP_ADMIN = "APP_ADMIN";
    public static final String PRO_ADMIN = "PRO_ADMIN";
    public static final String PRO_ADD_BOOKING = "PRO_ADD_BOOKING";
    public static final String PRO_EDIT_BOOKING = "PRO_EDIT_BOOKING";
    ...

    public static String[] allRolesButAPP_SYSTEM() {
        return new String[]{ APP_CLIENT, APP_PROFESSIONAL, ... };
    }
}


import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;

public class ProfessionalResourceIT {

    @WithMockUser(roles = {RolesConstants.allRolesButAPP_SYSTEM()})
    public void cannotGetIfNotSystem(){
        assertThat(...);
    }
}
```

> attribute value must be constant

Comment: By which dependency in your project is `WithMockUser` provided?

Comment: Have you tried, something like this @WithMockUser(roles = {RolesConstants.APP_SYSTEM, RolesConstants.APP_CLIENT, so on})

Comment: import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;

Comment: It does work but I have thousand of test and more than 10 roles i cannot add them this way I need a method or something

Comment: i would rewrite your constants to use enums instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this

```
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;

public class ProfessionalResourceIT {

    @WithMockUser(roles = {RolesConstants.APP_SYSTEM, RolesConstants.APP_CLIENT, so on})
    public void cannotGetIfNotSystem(){
        assertThat(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Antoine, have you tried my solution, is it working for you?

Comment: @Antoine,ohh not sure then, is there a way to achieve the same by passing the whole in one go..

Comment: @Antoine, Unfortunately, you can't do this with arrays, that is y edited my solution also, seems like you need to pass all the value one by one as shown above in my answer, we can have more info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067863/7414166

Comment: Actually that is exactly what I don't want to do (pass them all one by one) as I have more than 10 of "roles"

Comment: @Antoine, yeah can understand but it seems I don't have any other solution right now for this problem..