# Attribute must be constant when get a value from properties

Tags: java, path, constants, endpoint

I am working with Java javax.ws.rs.Path and I am getting the path from the properties. Even though the constant is final static I am the getting Attribute must be constant issue.

This is my how I am getting the value of my constant:

```
public static final String ENDPOINT_GET =ConfigurationProperties.getInstance().getProperty("someProperty");}
```

This is the method Implementation:

```
public String getProperty(String name) {
    return properties.getProperty(name);
  }
```

But I got this issue, in the other hand if I put this constant in the class directly I don't have this issue.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)

Comment: It needs to be a compile time constant.

Comment: So it  is not possible to get this from properties as far I understood.